# Hashing passwords for a login form in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, hashcode

I have a `Login form`, I haven't done anything about `hashing` the password yet, I have been reading about hash here and there yet it really confuses me and don't really know how to implement it in my code for the login form.
**Code for hashing I saw**

```
Dim bytes() as byte  = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringPassword);
dim  hashOfBytes() as byte = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(bytes)
Dim strHash as string = Convert.ToBase64String(hashOfBytes)
```

**Convert back to bytes**

```
hashOfBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strHash)
```

** My Login Form Code**

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = forms")
    Using cmd
        With cmd
            MsgBox("Connection Established")
            .Connection = conn
            .Parameters.Clear()
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY Username = @iUsername AND Password = @iPassword"
            .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iUsername", txtUser.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iPassword", txtPass.Text))

        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using
End Using

If dr.HasRows = 0 Then

    MsgBox("Invalid user")
    Conn.Close()

Else


    Start.Show()
    Conn.Close()


End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the hash value of the password in the Password field of your table.
Then you search for user and the password hash, not directly for the password taken from the input box.

However, your code will still fail because you try to use the MySqlDataReader after the disposing of the connection. Move the check for rows inside the Using block

```
 Dim strHash as string = Convert.ToBase64String(hashOfBytes)
 .....
 Dim userIsValid as Boolean = False
 Using conn As New MySqlConnection(.........)
 Using cmd
    ....
        .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iPassword", strHashPass))
        Try
            conn.Open()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            userIsValid = dr.HasRows
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
  End Using
  End Using

  if userIsValid then
      .....
  else
      .....
  End
```